# connecting lcd display to raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, microcontroller, raspbian, lcd, microprocessors

I am trying out online tutorial to practice python and raspberry pi. 
I am currently following this tutorial:
http://learn.adafruit.com/drive-a-16x2-lcd-directly-with-a-raspberry-pi/wiring

It says a potentiometer is needed, but i dont have one...
The lcd I have is JHD162A

what will happen if i connect the circuit exactly the same but without a potentiometer?
will it destroy my pi or will it not work?

Answer (score 1):

The pot is for the LCD contrast. If you do not connect it you will not destroy the LCD, but you might see nothing out of the LCD! You could try connecting pin 3 directly to 5V, this might give *too* high a contrast and it might come out completely black. If you have two fixed resistors, connect them in series, one end of the two to 5V, one end to ground and the junction of the two resistors to pin 3. A couple of 4k7 resistors would probably work fine.